# Using mock.patch.object() with sqlalchemy model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mocking, pytest

```
 class FooModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    __table_args__ = {
        "schema": "some_schema",
        "postgresql_partition_by": "RANGE (event_ts)",
    }
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        BigInteger,
        autoincrement=True,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    some_column: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
    event_ts: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, index=True)


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def mock_foo_model() -> Generator[None, None, None]:
    patched_model_class = copy.copy(FooModel)
    setattr(patched_model_class, "__table_args__", {
        "schema": "some_schema"
        # removed postgresql_partition_by field
    }) 
    with mock.patch.object(FooModel,patched_model_class):
        # it requires an attribute, but I want to swap it with another object, or the same 
        # one with changed __table_args__
        # I need to use patch.object() because this mock will propagate to entire application
        yield
```

I somehow need to mock my FooModel, I just want to change **table_args**, and keep the rest. I need to use patch.object() because this fixture will propagate to entire application. Is this possible?

With code above I get : `TypeError: attribute name must be string, not 'DeclarativeAttributeIntercept'`